# Pass through headers form Viewer request to origin request in AWS lambda@Edge

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-edge

Is there any possibility to pass through headers form viewer request to origin request without white listing the Vary headers in AWS Lambda@Edge.

Comment: There is a good reason why you need to whitelist headers in order to see them in the origin request trigger.  What, specifically, are you hoping to accomplish?

Comment: @Michael: I had an API, Which Verify JWT from Authorization header before response. If I whitelist this header, Cloud Front will cache based on this header. But for all request the the response will be same. So I cant whitelist the Authorization header.

Comment: *"But for all request the the response will be same"* is not likely to be always true.  What about unauthorized requests, where the `Authorization` header is incorrect or absent?  The response to this would not be the same as a valid request, would it?  If a header value potentially changes the origin server response, it has to be part of the cache key.  I understand that all *authorized* requests might have the same response, but if it is the origin that decides which requests are authorized, then this is where the problem arises.  Perhaps your scenario differs, somehow; if so, please advise.

Comment: As you mentioned, All the authorized requests will get the same response. If it is unauthorized, the response is 401 unauthorized and with out cache control header. For all the authorized request, The response will be same and have s-maxage cache control header & if I whitelist Authorization header CloudFront will cache based on the header & almost all the requests will forward to Origin.  My Authorization is token based. I can validate the token in Viewer-Request itself & if missed, I need to validate the token in Origin too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with the same header.
What I ended up doing, is that creating a lambda@edge in viewer request that copies `Authorization` to `X-Authorization` header, and then another lambda@edge that copies back from `X-Authorization` to `Authorization`.
This way the header is forwarded but not used for the cache key.

I also opened a ticket to AWS customer service begging to let me select which headers will be used for cache key. They will look into it.

Comment: They say they passed this requirement to the Lambda@Edge team. I don't know when they will implement it, if they will at all.